Boto3 start_backup_job Waiters
I have a script that automates restore jobs from AWS Backups.
I am taking guidance from this documentation of boto3: Backup - Boto3 documentation
I am using the function start_backup_job() to start a job and then describe_backup_job() to query the RecoveryPointArn.
I need to wait for the start backup job to be completed so that I can query the RecoveryPointArn. The issue here is that AWS Backup doesn't have any waiters defined in its documentation. Does someone know how to do this?
Also, going through the docs, I see the function get_waiter().
Why is this function available when there is no waiters defined for AWS Backup?

A waiter is just a pre-supplied function that loops until a particular response is obtained.
You can write the equivalent by calling describe_backup_job() every 10 seconds or so and checking whether it returns a RecoveryPointArn.

This is the way! You keep calling describe until you get a response, then proceed with what you want to do!
